Add period/full stop to the end of an expanded macro if it doesn't end with one. Alternative to `xstring` with macro expansion?
This question is similar to multiple other ones (e.g. for captions), however I couldn't manage to use them for the following MWE.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifdefempty
\usepackage{xstring} % for \IfEndWith

\fullexpandarg  % doesn't seem to do anything...
\newcommand{\addfullstop}[1]{%
%  \StrExpand[100]{#1}{\inputval}%
%  \IfEndWith{\inputval}{.}{\inputval}{\inputval.}%
  \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{#1}{#1.}%
}

\newcommand{\theString}{}

\newcommand{\updateTheStringWithPeriod}[1]{%
  \ifdefempty{\theString}{%
    \renewcommand{\theString}{\addfullstop{\protect#1}}%
  }{%
    \appto\theString{ \addfullstop{\protect#1}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\updateTheStringWithoutPeriod}[1]{%
  \ifdefempty{\theString}{%
    \renewcommand{\theString}{#1}%
  }{%
    \appto\theString{ #1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\printTheString}{%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  How to get \addfullstop to work here?
%  \addfullstop{%
    \theString%
%  }%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}

\begin{document}
Initial string value: \printTheString

\updateTheStringWithPeriod{Now there's text.}
Now the value is: \printTheString

\updateTheStringWithoutPeriod{Final text}
With some more text: \printTheString

\end{document}

The output is:
Initial string value:
Now the value is: Now there's text.
With some more text: Now there's text. Final text

Note how the paragraph does not end with a full stop.
I couldn't find a simple expandable alternative for \IfEndWith. From what I understood from this SO answer, this just isn't possible using xstring.
I'd rather avoid using expl3, but I'll accept answers using it.

You can create your own testing macro \isfinalperiod{text}\iffalse:
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\long\def\isfinalperiod#1{\isfinalperiodA#1\end.\end\relax}
\long\def\isfinalperiodA#1.\end#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax \expandafter\unless\fi}
\long\def\updatestringwithperiod#1{%
   \ifx\thestring\empty \else \addto\thestring{ }\fi
   \addto\thestring{#1}%
   \isfinalperiod{#1}\iffalse \addto\thestring{.}\fi
}

\def\thestring{}

Initial string value: \thestring

\updatestringwithperiod{Now there's text.}
Now the value is: \thestring

\updatestringwithperiod{Final text}
With some more text: \thestring

\bye

How \isfinalperiod works. Suppose that we have a text without final period, for example
\isfinalperiod{text}\iffalse

expands to
\isfinalperiodA text\end.\end\relax\iffalse

The #1 of \isfinalperiodA is separated by .\end, so #1 is
text\end and #2 is empty. \isfinalperiodA expands to
\ifx\relax\relax \expandafter\unless\fi \iffalse

and because \relax is equal to \relax, the \ifx condition is true and it expands to
\unless \iffalse

i.e. the following text after \iffalse is processed to \fi.
Now, suppose, that we have text. with final period. The expansions are
\isfinalperiod{text.}\iffalse
\isfinalperiodA text.\end.\end\relax \iffalse

Now, the #1 is text and #2 is .\end. The \isfinalperiodA macro expands to
\ifx\relax.\end\relax \expandafter\unless\fi \iffalse

Because \relax is not equal to ., the \ifx condition is false and all text is skipped to the \fi. What remains:
\iffalse

The next text after \iffalse is skipped to the \fi.

With expl3. I'd store in a sequence, so there's no clumsy test for emptiness when adding. At the end the sequence is used with a space between items and the same check is done for a trailing period.
With \str_range:nnn {<string>} {-1} {-1} we can access the last item.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_breno_string_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\updateTheStringWithPeriod}{m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Ne \l_breno_string_seq
   {
    \breno_string_addperiod:n {#1}
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\updateTheStringWithoutPeriod}{m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Ne \l_breno_string_seq {#1}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printTheString}{}
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_breno_string_seq
   {
    \breno_string_addperiod:e { \seq_use:Nn \l_breno_string_seq {~} }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \breno_string_addperiod:n
 {% we need \exp_not:n because this is passed to \seq_put_right:Ne
  \exp_not:n {#1}
  % test the last character: if it's a period do nothing
  % otherwise add one
  \str_if_eq:eeF {.} {\str_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 } } {.}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \breno_string_addperiod:n {e}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Initial string value: +\printTheString+ % + to see that nothing is printed

\updateTheStringWithPeriod{Now \textbf{there's} text.}
Now the value is: \printTheString

\updateTheStringWithoutPeriod{Final text}
With some more text: \printTheString

\updateTheStringWithPeriod{and last text}
With further text: \printTheString

\end{document}


The command \printTheString is fully expandable and will work inside \edef or \write.
If your aim is just to print a trailing period and not to play further with the material, you can just use the space factor.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_breno_string_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\updateTheStringWithPeriod}{m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_breno_string_seq
   {
    #1 \addperiod
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\updateTheStringWithoutPeriod}{m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Ne \l_breno_string_seq {#1}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printTheString}{}
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_breno_string_seq
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_breno_string_seq {~} \addperiod
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\addperiod}{\ifnum\spacefactor=\sfcode`. \else.\fi}

\begin{document}

Initial string value: +\printTheString+ % + to see that nothing is printed

\updateTheStringWithPeriod{Now \textbf{there's} text.}
Now the value is: \printTheString

\updateTheStringWithoutPeriod{Final text}
With some more text: \printTheString

\updateTheStringWithPeriod{and last text}
With further text: \printTheString

\end{document}

